# Oracle APEX - find pages that contain a particular region type

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

Is there a way to get list of pages in Oracle APEX where a particular region exists? For example get a list of all pages that contain Breadcumbs or Classic Report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is relatively easy to figure out. You have access to the public apex views that are like a data dictionary on top of the apex metadata. The best way to start is to check who the apex user is by running the following query:

`select distinct owner from all_objects where object_name like 'APEX%';`

Then use the user that corresponds to your version (in my case that is APEX_190100 since I'm on 19.1) and list all apex views

`select * from all_objects where owner = 'APEX_190100';`

That list isn't that long you'll quickly find the view you need. Query that view by application_id and look for the information you need. In your case that probably is

```
SELECT * FROM apex_application_page_regions;
```

Breadcrumbs has its own view: APEX_APPLICATION_BREADCRUMBS.

You can also see the list of Application Express views (and a short description) via app builder > workspace utilities > Application Express Views

Comment: A better method to find such views is using the view APEX_DICTIONARY

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely! In fact, this is one of the advantages of APEX being a metadata-driven framework. Go to the Application Builder > Workspace Utilities > Application Express Views. That will give you a listing of all of the views available for you to run the type of reports you're asking about. The Query By Example pages there can be helpful, or you can start running queries in the SQL Workshop:

```
select application_id,
  application_name,
  page_id,
  page_name,
  component_signature
from apex_application_page_regions
where instr(component_signature, 'NATIVE_BREADCRUMB') > 0
```

Other regions have different signatures, like NATIVE_SQL_REPORT (Classic Report), NATIVE_IG (Interactive Grid), and NATIVE_IR (Interactive Report).

Also, when you're at Application Builder > Workspace Utilities, look on the right for a number of more "canned" reports you may find useful.